# Django: 1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint' on model with only one field

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a `Salad` model:

```
class Salad(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

No matter how I call the class, the single field, what models I put instead of `Profile`, or whichever `on_delete` option I choose. I systematically get the error:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')`

The error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
  Applying playerdata.0053_auto_20180724_1943...    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:/Python/DjangoProjects/rolegate\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 90, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 117, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

Comment: Are you using `MyISAM` engine ?

Comment: I don't know what that is so I guess I am not.

Comment: Wait, I see in mysql workbench that the new model is created with InnoDB, but that all the others are with myISAM indeed!
Knowing that I am working locally with a database that I imported from my production server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally it is caused by the fact that your two related tables are not using InnoDB and at least one of them uses MyISAM engine instead.

**The problem is [Foreign keys are not supported on MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).**

Here is a related Django ticket [#26777](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26777).

Since this is entirely related to MYSQL and not a Django specific, I will link this thread that could potentially help you,

[Converting Tables from MyISAM to InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)

**FUN FACT**

I'm not the one that took care of this Django ticket even if the names are similar. @SimonCharette is.